# How to make a text clickable in iphone sms?

Tags: iphone

I need to make a text as a clickable link in iphone sms. I just want to know if it can done or not?

If yes then please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a UIControl above your text which handles the touch events.

Comment: Sorry, I than I misunderstood your question.